# Test fails when adding redux-offline in store. (Puppeter)

Tags: node.js, redux, mocha.js, puppeteer, redux-offline

Store.js

```
const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger);

export const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(middleware, offline(offlineConfig))
);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

My test runs fine when there is no offline(offlineConfig) in the store. But when offline(offlineConfig) is added, test shows

```
1) "before all" hook:
     Error: Timeout of 30000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

Is there any solution to run my mocha test successfully adding offline package??

Additional info:

[image]

Due to this page does not load and test fails.

Comment: What does your *before all* function look like?

Comment: before(async () => {
 // pupperter code 
});
@ThomasDondorf

Comment: Is the error you added thrown from inside your `before` function? What does the corresponding code look like?

Comment: Yes. Problem is that page does not load so it can't find the id they are looking for. Hence it finally times out.

Comment: Well, there you have your solution ;) So, the real question is why the page does not load? Maybe you can add some of the relevant code.

Comment: hmm looks like the question should have been why I'm getting that undefined issue. :D Thank you. I'll do some research on it. @ThomasDondorf